# Where do the hordes spawn with the latest map expansion (Horse Lords)?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Given the Horse Lord expands the map quite to the east along the Siberian wastelands, do the hordes spawn earlier/in the middle of the map or they still arrive in the usual period and from outside the map?
I have searched on the wiki, but it does not deal with this DLC explicitely.

Comment: Pre-horse lords, they spawned in Khiva, next to the steppes north of India. Now that horse-lords has expanded the map again, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Studoku now that you mention it, I did not notice this before: I have not the DLC, but I have the extra map locations of horse lords. strange.

Comment: Every map expansion has come 'for free' when the main version of the game is updated. So Rajas of India added all of the subcontinent 300+ provinces even if you hadn't bought the expansion. Ditto Sword of Islam adding Mail (~10 provinces), and Horse Lords adding central Asia, 27 provinces. If you turned off Rajas and Sword, you'd still have the same map. Good question, though.

Comment: @Dacio thanks, I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, as apparently noone has yet checked in-game, I went to look at the game files.

There is a new event (ID: 60500) with flag "mongol_empire_arrival" that takes the place of the sequence "mongol_horde_rumors/il_khanate_arrival/golden_horde_arrival".
The new event trigger is in the year 1210 (so 5 years earlier than the previous event).

Also, no matter if you have Horse Lords or not, Temujin (AKA: Genghis Khan) spawns in "Ordu Baliq", ID 1457 (that apparently in game is known as "Kara Khorum"). With the new expansion changes only the name of the CB (tribal vs nomad invasion).

The information is contained in the "mongols_events" file.